# In Vim CLI, is it possible to imitate ":browse old" and create a menu?

Tags: vim

In Vim CLI (with a script, and without relying on a plugin), is it possible to imitate :

```
:browse old
```

and create a numbered menu (e.g.of scripts) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`inputlist`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#inputlist%28%29)?

```
 " build your list in whatever way is appropriate for your task
let somelist = map(range(1,&lines-2), '"Item #".v:val')

let numberedlist = map(copy(somelist), 'string(v:key+1).": ".v:val')
let chosen = inputlist(['Pick an item:'] + numberedlist)
if 0 < chosen && chosen < len(somelist)
  echo 'User chose item #' . chosen . ': <<<' . somelist[chosen-1] . '>>>'
else
  echo 'Invalid selection!'
endif
```

Comment: Thank you very much and please excuse my late answer. I had thought my question was, well, uninteresting... I shall now try (being novice in vimscript) to put your solution to work. FYI, I use Vim on my MB, but also on an Android phone (VimTouch, which is a fine implementation), and a menu may be a good solution - sometimes - to cope with a cramped keyboard. By the way, am I mistaken to think that input(), inputlist(), etc... are underused functionalities ? Thanks again.

Comment: Probably `input()` and `intputlist()` are less used because they do not fit directly into the usual “mode” behavior of Vim (insert mode, normal mode, line ranges, registers, text objects, et cetera). They are not totally unused (e.g. [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) uses `input()` to prompt for complex surroundings like HTML/XML tags). If there is no good way to specify the required input via one of the usual means, then a prompt is probably fine (as long as the user knows to expect it).